# Edit build.prop file in WSA Windows Android

Tags: android, windows-subsystem-for-android

I successfully gained root access over my WSA installation. The thing is that I need to edit the build.prop file, but no matter what I tried, I couldn't edit this file. With the app build.prop editor, or any root file browser, the WSA enviroment just suddenly crashes or prompts a message like "couldn't acces the file" or "not permited".

**How can I edit this build.prop file? Any ideas?**

- I tried to use build.prop editor, but when it opens the WSA just crashes. With Root Browser, when I try to edit the file, the WSA also crashes.
- I also tried to rename/replace the file with LAN DRIVE, but even though it appears as if I have successfully pasted a file at /system, when I refresh the page over Windows File Explorer, the file either isn't there or haven't actually replaced the original build.prop file.
- I also tried adb root, but it returns me the following:
  `C:\platform-tools>adb root adbd cannot run as root in production builds`
- Adb push also didn't work as expected for me:
  `C:\platform-tools>adb push build.prop /system/ build.prop: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 0.2 MB/s (2735 bytes in 0.015s) adb: error: failed to copy 'build.prop' to '/system/build.prop': remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system`

Answer (score 0):

try to remount system to RW again before edit .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).